# Sourcing quotes scope question

Tags: discussion, scope

There is currently [this question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/need-source-for-bruce-lee-quote?noredirect=1#comment17284_8244) on the main site, regarding the source of a quote attributed to Bruce Lee. It has (currently) two upvotes, one downvote, and one vote to close (VTC) as "not related to martial arts".

The relevant portion of the [help section about on topic questions](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has as the first bullet point:

- *Characteristics, regimens, history, and culture of martial arts systems worldwide*

I considered this to be something about the mindset and culture of JKD, as Bruce Lee was the founder of that system, and sourced/answered it. However, it was pointed out that this could potentially also open the door for asking about random quotes from joe martial artist:

> @JohnP We absolutely should. Opening the page to questions about the sources of quotes from martial artists invites a lot of nonsense. "Hey guys, when did Chuck Liddell say "I'll fight somebody in my backyard for free, just to see if I'm better than him."?"

As pointed out, it *could* be considered a gray area, so I'm looking for a more concrete reference that we can point to.

As I see it, there are three options, and I would like to get the community feedback on which direction we want to pursue, and once there is a consensus we can point to this meta as justification. The three options would be

1. No. Sourcing quotes is not in scope.
2. Yes. Sourcing quotes is in scope.
3. Yes, with the proviso that the quote itself goes towards the mindset and culture of the art in question. (Which would almost self limit it to founders and major contributors to said art).

Please answer and/or vote towards which you would like to support.

Answer (score 5):

I lean toward option #3 for two main reasons.

1) Sourcing quotes related to martial arts could, as @JohnP stated, fall under "culture of martial arts systems"

2) I hate to discourage anyone from using the SE. If a question is borderline allowable, I lean toward allowing it, even if it pains the martial arts elitist inside me.

Here's the problem: Every single related question would be open to interpretation of relevance. The Chuck Liddell quote I posted is a real quote, and is relevant to the mindset of some (mostly oldschool) MMA fighters. I don't think that means it warrants a Q/A or discussion here. Though I like the Bruce Lee quote, it seems like very general and vague life advice, and therefore not martial arts related (even if he was referring to martial arts).

It seems like a coin flip, so I'll remove my close vote if the majority of meta users agree that it should stay.

Comment: Possibly somethin along the lines of "on topic if it contributes to the understanding of the art/philopsy"? Or similarish wording? That would limit the random quote seekers

Comment: @JohnP That sounds good!